# Is there a way to wipe a device based on a certain password? A like a "Wipe-me" password?

Tags: security, password, privacy

Is there a way (an app perhaps) that will wipe a phone if a certain password is entered at the lock screen? For example "letmein" unlocks the phone, but if you enter "wipeme" it will start the factory reset process, or erase the decryption key or what have you.

Comment: What purpose should this serve? Is your use case *cop/gangster/whoever forces me to unlock it but I enter "wipeme" instead*? To give you a hint: This is technically possible - *but* - the unlock is done by the system itself and an app cannot intercept it (for obvious reasons). In short: Not happening on stock firmwares, someone (you?) would have to code it himself right into a custom ROM.

Comment: @ce4 I like that reasoning ;)

Comment: @ce4 The scenario sounded silly when brought to my attention too, but I am researching it nonetheless. I would think the user would be advised to worry more about their well-being than the data on the phone. Requiring a custom ROM is the type of answer I was looking for. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Custom ROMs will not just magically support this. Someone has to implement it, e.g. for CyanogenMod and the person who wants that feature has to use a phone that can be modded (i.e. an *unsubsidized* Nexus 4, not a locked one from VZW/ATT/etc.). BTW: The easiest /fastest way would likely be to use a full-encrypted phone and just delete the key on the /efs partition (/efs/userdata_footer). Encryption details are [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=25635462&postcount=54)

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to do this, although you *could* do it using SMS.

You would have to install an app like [Cerberus](http://www.cerberusapp.com) which allows you to send an SMS to wipe your device.

Answer (score 1):

There is none in my knowledge. The good reason why its not there because if its applied to specific models then anyone who owns the same model and knew the code can erase your privacy. So its not a good idea.